# Meteor login redirecting to /action

Tags: authentication, meteor, meteor-accounts

I have a application that i've been developing for about a month, the authentication was one of the first tasks that i took care of, and it has been working fine. Today i went to test the app the the local authentication is working but whenever i use Google or Facebook login it always redirects to "http://localhost:3000/action" and because of that path doesn't exists i get the following error:

There is no route for the path: /action

Any ideas on why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the `Meteor.loginWithFacebook` method? There may be something in the method that causes the redirect.

I'm not too familiar with the External Service login methods, but I would try:

1. Checking the method to see if it's causing a redirect;
2. Temporary workaround would be to set up a route in your router for /action and redirect it to wherever you want to go

Answer (score 0):

Was not using event.preventDefault() before Meteor.loginWithFacebook method